# How to allow a user to resubmit a form without a warning

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I believe it will be a poor question, because most people wants to prevent a form from beeing resubmited but I'll need the exact opposit of it.

That means a user should be allowed to reload a page and the form values have to be posted each time (Session Variables are not possible in this cenario)
Normally the user gets the annoying warning message of the browser. 
Is it possible to turn this warning off or simply resubmit the form (eg. with jQuery)

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could overwrite `alert` and empty the function with `alert = function(){}`. Check this example:

```js
alert("test");
alert = function(){};
alert("test2");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot turn off this alert (in a good way), but you can redirect to the same form, with all fields auto-compiled, so if you re-do a submit, it won't ask you a confirm.
You can redirect with a _GET parameter, and if your code detect this, it will check for all values to insert in the form.

Something like this:

form.php

```
<?php
if(!empty($_GET['param'])) {
    /* Pseudo code */
    $data = query_and_fetch("select 'value_1' as field_1 from yourtable WHERE wfield='".escape($_GET['param'])."' ;");
}
?>

<form method='post' action='process.php'>
    <input name='field_1' value='<?=isset($data['field_1']) ? $data['field_1'] : ''?>/>
    <input type='submit' value='submit'/>
</form>
```

process.php

```
<?php
header("location: form.php?param=123");
?>
```